# If I have a PHP string in the format YYYY-DD-MM and a timestamp in MySQL, is there a good way to convert between them?

Tags: php, mysql, time, timestamp, date

I'm interested in doing comparisons between the date string and the MySQL timestamp. However, I'm not seeing an easy conversion. Am I overlooking something obvious?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Converting from timestamp to format:

```
date('Y-m-d', $timestamp);
```

Converting from formatted to timestamp:

```
mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, $day, $year, $is_dst);
```

See [date](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) and [mktime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php) for further documentation.

When it comes to storing it's up to you whether to use the MySQL DATE format for stroing as a formatted date; as an integer for storing as a UNIX timestamp; or you can use MySQL's TIMESTAMP format which converts a numeric timestamp into a readable format. [Check the MySQL Doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/datetime.html) for TIMESTAMP info.

Answer (score 3):

You can avoid having to use `strtotime()` or `getdate()` in **PHP** by using MySQL's `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` function.

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(timestamp) FROM sometable
```

The resulting data will be a standard integer Unix timestamp, so you can do a direct comparison to `time()`.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote this little function to simplify the process:

```
/**
 * Convert MySQL datetime to PHP time
 */
function convert_datetime($datetime) {
  //example: 2008-02-07 12:19:32
  $values = split(" ", $datetime);

  $dates = split("-", $values[0]);
  $times = split(":", $values[1]);

  $newdate = mktime($times[0], $times[1], $times[2], $dates[1], $dates[2], $dates[0]);

  return $newdate;
}
```

I hope this helps

Comment: This whole function can be replaced by a single call to strtotime. Why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: My bad, I built this as I was having issues in the past (for a reason that escapes me now).

Answer (score 0):

[strtotime()](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) and [getdate()](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.getdate.php) are two functions that can be used to get dates from strings and timestamps. There isn't a standard library function that converts between MySQL and PHP timestamps though.

Answer (score 0):

Use the PHP [Date](http://il2.php.net/date) function. You may have to convert the mysql timestamp to a Unix timestamp in your query using the [UNIX_TIMESTAMP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html) function in mysql.

Answer (score 0):

A date string of the form:

```
YYYY-MM-DD
```

has no time associated with it. A MySQL Timestamp is of the form:

```
YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss
```

to compare the two, you'll either have to add a time to the date string, like midnight for example

```
$datetime = '2008-08-21'.' 00:00:00';
```

and then use a function to compare the epoc time between them

```
if (strtotime($datetime) > strtotime($timestamp)) {
    echo 'Datetime later';
} else {
    echo 'Timestamp equal or greater';
}
```